# Want to create comparison matrix from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me on creation of comparison matrix from mySQL table. 
I have following table.

```
MRP | Brand | USAGE
10 | ABC | 200 MB
10 | XYZ | 300 MB
20 | ABC | 500 MB
30 | XYZ | 600 MB
```

I want a query which gives following result.

```
MRP | ABC | XYZ
10 | 200 MB | 300 MB
20 | 500 MB |-----------
30 | -----------| 600 MB
```

can I achieve this using PHP?
thanks and regards.

Comment: You even can achieve this using MySQL, you should look for pivot tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want what's called a pivot table.

something like:

```
SELECT MRP,
    MAX(IF(Brand='ABC', USAGE,0)) as 'ABC',
    MAX(IF(Brand='XYZ', USAGE,0)) as 'XYZ'
FROM table
GROUP BY MRP;
```

See this article for more info:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
SELECT  MRP,
        MAX(CASE WHEN BRAND = 'ABC' THEN `USAGE` ELSE NULL END) 'ABC',
        MAX(CASE WHEN BRAND = 'XYZ' THEN `USAGE` ELSE NULL END) 'XYZ'
FROM tableName
GROUP BY MRP
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4776/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to achieve this with [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement like this one:

```
SELECT MRP
     ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE Brand WHEN 'ABC' THEN `USAGE` ELSE NULL END) AS ABC
     ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE Brand WHEN 'XYZ' THEN `USAGE` ELSE NULL END) AS XYZ
FROM myTable GROUP BY MRP;
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47eae/5)